GEE Error: "Unable to transform edge" when using reduceRegion in a function
I have a land cover dataset and a point feature collection, and I am trying to calculate two pieces of information to the feature collection: 1) the mode underlying land cover within a specific buffer around each point, and 2) a dictionary of land covers and their areas within the same buffer around each point. I want to set these two things as properties to each original feature. Here is my code:
// Land cover
var LC = ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-public/assets/brazil/lulc/collection9/mapbiomas_collection90_integration_v1').select('classification_2020').clip(brazil);

// feature Collection
var fires = fires_type2.filterBounds(ROI);

// Region of interest
var filterROI = ee.Filter.bounds(ROI);  
fires = fires.filter(filterROI);

var getModeLCinBuffers = function(feature) {  //Create buffers around points (if snapping is needed use code chunk above)
  var roundBuffer = feature.buffer(ee.Number(375).divide(2)); //create a 375 m squared buffer to match VIIRS res at nadir
  var squareBuffer = roundBuffer.bounds();
  //Let's combine buffer-making with finding the mode LC in the buffer (below)
  var mode_LC = LC.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(),                    //use mode reducer
      geometry: ee.Feature(squareBuffer).geometry(), //cast feature as geometry
      scale: scale,
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      tileScale: 8 
    });
  // returns a dict with the mode. 
  
  // Get areas of all LCs within the buffers
  var img = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000000);
  var lc_areas = img.addBands(LC)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'remapped'
    }),
    geometry: ee.Feature(squareBuffer).geometry(),
    scale: scale,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e12
  }).get('groups');

  // Assign this info to the original feature.
  feature = feature.set('375m_mode_LC_2020', mode_LC.get('remapped'))//.set('all_LC_areas', lc_areas); // or 'classification_2020' //use .get() to get property of feature
  return feature;
};

var modeLCigs = fires.map(getModeLCinBuffers); //map the function over all our points
print(modeLCigs.limit(10), 'modeLCigs'); // just printing 10 features to check them


When printing the resulting feature collection, I keep getting the error message: "FeatureCollection (Error)
Unable to transform edge (-75320.000000, 44152.000000 to -75319.999863, 44152.000000) from EPSG:32623 PLANAR [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -30.0, 0.0] to EPSG:4326."
However, the code runs fine when I only include the first reduceRegion (where I'm getting a mode) and exclude the second (where I'm getting a dictionary).
I realize my code might not be the most efficient, but how do I fix this error? What is going wrong here?
